# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.selectedData.push') - Can't add payload to state using Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm having an issue using Redux Toolkit. I want to push an object to my initial state called selectedData which is an array, this gives me the error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.selectedData.push')".

I've been following https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers and they literally write their reducer logic the same as mine. I have no idea why it doesn't work for me.

Their code example:

```
const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    todoAdded(state, action) {
      // "Mutate" the existing state, no return value needed
      state.push(action.payload)
    },
    todoDeleted(state, action.payload) {
      // Construct a new result array immutably and return it
      return state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload)
    }
  }
})
```

My code

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


export const exerciseItemSlice = createSlice({
    name: "exerciseItem",
    initialState: { selectedData: [] },
    reducers: {
        saveSelectedItemIdsToRedux: (state, action) => {
            state.selectedData.push(action.payload);

        },
        resetSelectedItemIds(state, action) {
            return state.itemSelectedData;
        }

    },

}


);

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { saveSelectedItemIdsToRedux, resetSelectedItemIds } = exerciseItemSlice.actions;


export default exerciseItemSlice.reducer;
```

The only difference is that I'm passing a state called selectedData, I have tried with initialState only as well.

**EDIT: Updating with all relevant code as the issue can't be reproduced with above code, indicating the issue should be somewhere else?**

rootReducer.js

```
import counterReducer from "./counterSlice";
import texterReducer from "./testSlice";
import setsTextReducer from "./setsTextSlicer";
import templateReducer from "./templateSlice";
import setsScreenReducer from "./setsScreenSlice";
import exerciseBrowserReducer from "./exerciseBrowserSlice";
import exerciseItemReducer from "./exerciseItemSlice";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counter: counterReducer,
    texter: texterReducer,
    setsText: setsTextReducer,
    template: templateReducer,
    setsScreen: setsScreenReducer,
    exercise: exerciseBrowserReducer,
    exerciseItem: exerciseItemReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import {
    persistStore,
    persistReducer,
    FLUSH,
    REHYDRATE,
    PAUSE,
    PERSIST,
    PURGE,
    REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    version: 1,
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    //blacklist: [rootReducer.exerciseItem]
};



const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,

    // https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            },

        })
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store };
```

**UPDATE**

I did the good old remove and re-add and now it's working. Renamed the slice/reducer as it had the same name as another component(Feels weird but that might have been the issue?). I've compared my old code to the now working and I can't find any difference, so my best bet would be that the renaming was the issue.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but try: `state.selectedData= [...state.selectedData, action.payload];`. If it doesn't work, try to initialize the array with some dummy value, just to check if it will then work.

Comment: @sagi thanks for your reply. I've tried with the dummy data before but it's the same issue. Trying with the snippet you suggested gives me error ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]') ```

Comment: Last attempt, try again with the dummy data on initial state and use `[...state.selectedData, ...action.payload];`

Comment: [I can't reproduce this error](https://codesandbox.io/s/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-state-selecteddata-push-c-xguct?file=/src/redux.ts). Check the rest of your code.

Comment: @Summer well, I'm logging the payload in the reducer. So dispatching works. I had this code in another slice earlier and there it worked. I've copied and paste that code over, I know the issue is somewhere else in my code but I need some pointers. I'll update with all relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Redux persists serialize (converting to string) your state data in order saved in  Async Storage. After serialization, you can't access the array method including `Array.push`.

Try to parse the array before using the array method.

```
 saveSelectedItemIdsToRedux: (state, action) => {

const serializedData = JSON.parse(state.selectedData)

state.selectedData = serializedData.push(action.payload);

        }
```

**Note:** JSON.parse sometimes fails when you work with an array with nested objects.

Comment: If it is, then `undefined` error should not come.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got it working now. Updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps! Remove arrow function and use it like

```js
export const exerciseItemSlice = createSlice({
    name: "exerciseItem",
    initialState: { selectedData: [] },
    reducers: {
        // below line is the change
        saveSelectedItemIdsToRedux(state, action){
            state.selectedData.push(action.payload);

        },
        resetSelectedItemIds(state, action) {
            return state.itemSelectedData;
        }

    },

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the arrow function should work as per their documentation. Got it working now however, updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and figured out this: With redux-toolkit, each reducer owns its slice of state, so at the time you call state in

```
 state.selectedData.push(action.payload);
```

you're in fact calling State => selectedData => selectedData whitch is undefined

For use your selectedData inside a reducer's function with the createSlice API just call state and it means State => selectedData.

then you must change from this:

```
reducers: {
        saveSelectedItemIdsToRedux: (state, action) => {
            state.selectedData.push(action.payload);

        },
        resetSelectedItemIds(state, action) {
            return state.itemSelectedData;
        }

    },
```

to this

```
reducers: {
        saveSelectedItemIdsToRedux: (state, action) => {
            state.push(action.payload);

        },
        resetSelectedItemIds(state, action) {
            return state;
        }

    },
```

and it will work :-D